# equals(Object obj)" should be overridden along with the "compareTo(T obj)" method

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am writing a comparable class.  I have overridden compareTo method to sort my objects based on date in descending order.

public class Employee implements Comparable
{

```
private Timestamp joinDate;

public Timestamp getJoinDate()
{
    return joinDate;
}

public void setJoinDate(Timestamp joinDate)
{
    this.joinDate = joinDate;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Employee a)
{
    //sort employess based on join date desc
    return a.getJoinDate().compareTo(this.getJoinDate());
}
```

}

My Sonar is complaing to override equals method.

How do I override equals method here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to override the method `compareTo`, you have to use the *same* signature. The actual signature uses an `Object` parameter:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Object o)
{
    return ((Employee) o).getJoinDate().compareTo(joinDate);
}
```

Note that you have to explicitly *cast* the object `obj` to `Employee`, otherwise you won't be able to call its method `getJoinDate()`.

**Edit:** If you want to override the `equals()` method you can return the result of comparing the attributes `joinDate`:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj)
{
    return joinDate.equals(((Employee) obj).getJoinDate());
}
```

**Note:** It's not necessary to call `getJoinDate()` inside the `Employee` class, so you can just do:

```
return ((Employee) o).joinDate.compareTo(joinDate);
```

or

```
return joinDate.equals(((Employee) obj).joinDate);
```

Comment: My sonar complains that I also need to override equals method. Can you help me how do I override equals method here

Comment: @Patan edited. Note that you can use `joinDate` directly instead of calling `getJoinDate()`.

Comment: Are you sure that two employees should be considered equal if their join dates are the same? What if they're completely different people? A better solution would be to change compareTo to return super.compareTo if the two dates are equal, and suppress the warning.

Answer (score 2):

Include this on your class (when you override equals, you have to also override hashCode):

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((joinDate == null) ? 0 : joinDate.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Snippet other = (Snippet) obj;
    if (joinDate == null) {
        if (other.joinDate != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!joinDate.equals(other.joinDate))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between what what is indicated by `.equals() == true` and `.compareTo(...) == 0`. `equals()` method is intended to check whether two objects are **equal**, while `compareTo` is intended to set a relation order between elements, whether one is greater then the other, other is greater then the first one, or none of this is applicable which is typically means that objects are equal.

Unless you have a **very good reason**, you should override both `equals` and `compareTo`. An example of very good reason is `BigDecimal` class where `equals` compares both value of the object and its scale, while `compareTo` compares only values.

For your case, I'd override `equals()` like this:

```
@Override 
public int hashCode() {
    return this.getJoinDate().hashCode();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    //correct argument check
    if (!(obj instanceof Employee)) {
         return false;
    }

    //check nulls
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    Employee other = (Employee) obj;
    if (this.getJoinDate() == null) {
        return other.getJoinDate() == null;
    }
    return this.getJoinDate().equals(other.getJoinDate());
}
```